# shadcn/radix/react: NavigationMenuTrigger with asChild not possible - React.Children.only expected to receive a single React element child

Tags: css, reactjs, typescript, radix-ui, shadcnui

I use the newest version of shadcn for developing.
Now I want to use the Button as the menu trigger.

```
<NavigationMenuTrigger asChild>
  <Button variant="outline">
    <CircleUserRound></CircleUserRound>test
  </Button>       
</NavigationMenuTrigger>
```

I always get the following error:

```
Unhandled Runtime Error

Error: React.Children.only expected to receive a single React element child.
```

But there is only the button an child, there are not multiple children.
How can I fix this?

I tried to find answer via the search engine and inspected other code parts of working code.

Answer (score 1):

you have two "children" in button.. use fragment for that

```
<NavigationMenuTrigger asChild>
  <Button variant="outline">
    <><CircleUserRound></CircleUserRound>test</>
  </Button>       
</NavigationMenuTrigger>
```